# Array List Unshift

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> initgenome = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(4990, 0));
array_unshift(initgenome, 10, 1);
```

I am brand new to java. I am trying to construct a 5,000 gene genome. I want 4990 of the genes to have a 0 for their gene and the first 10 genes to have a 1 as the gene. I was looking online, and a site I found said array_unshift would shift whatever I wanted to the front of the array. I don't know how to check if this code actually is pushing 10 1s to the front of the array or if it is just starting off with a lot of 10s and a lot of 1s? Is this code actually telling the array to only put 10 1s at the beginning of the ArrayList?

Comment: `new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(10, 1).addAll(Collections.nCopies(4990, 0)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an efficient way to create your list:

```
// Create your list with a proper initial capacity
List<Integer> initgenome = new ArrayList<>(5_000);
// Add the 10 first values
initgenome.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, 1));
// Add the rest
initgenome.addAll(Collections.nCopies(4990, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is this :

```
ArrayList.addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)
```

This prepends the list with what you want, while taking care of not deleting any element.

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
So you could do something like this:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
//Now, Add all the numbers you want in myList
```

Then prepend that collection to your initgenome like this:

```
initgenome.add(0, myList);
```